# No cargan los archivos estáticos desde que borre el cache

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Tengo un problema que me esta volviendo loco, mis archivos estáticos estaban cargando de forma exitosa, pero por alguna razón elimine el caché del navegador y desde entonces no me cargan.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(('apps.blog.urls', 'blog'))),
]
```

Comment: por lo que veo no esta cargando ninguno... soy mas de flask que de django pero revisa bien las referencias a los archivos estaticos, si solo borraste el cache, es raro que no carguen

Comment: Ninguno carga, ya revise a detalle la referencia a los archivos estáticos, de igual forma estaban funcionando antes de borrar el caché. :'(

Comment: Muy probablemente si te funcionaban antes de borrar la cache y ahora no sea porque esos archivos no están en la ruta correcta en el servidor _pero lo estuvieron_. Cuando sí eran servidos correctamente, el navegador guardó una copia de ellos en caché. Después quizás borraste o reconfiguraste esos archivos que dejaron de estar accesibles, pero no notabas nada porque el navegador ni siquiera los pedía al servidor, usando en cambio los cacheados. Al borrar la cache, el navegador los pide de nuevo y ahora el error es visible. Prueba a imprimir `STATICFILES_DIRS` y verifica que muestre la ruta buena

Comment: @abulafia Tienes razón, imprimo `STATICFILES_DIRS` y las rutas no coinciden